# in javascript, is it possible for a NEW function to return NULL?

Tags: javascript, object, null

a function can return `null`, but is there any way for the `new` instance of a function to return null?

for example, in this silly code (strictly for purposes of illustration)

```
var f = function(j) { if( j > 5 ) return null; this.j = j; };
for( var f1=f(1); f1; f1=f(fi.j) ) {
   ...
}
```

what the code does not do is have `new f()` return null - it seems when `new` the return value is simply being thrown away.  here `new f()` has not guts at all except `__proto__`, but refuses to nullify itself.

is the reasonable alternative to look for a gutless "object" being returned?  if so, not knowing before hand what the "object" supposed to look like, what would be the best way to test for this?

---

solution:

considering that javascript's `new` cannot fail - it must return an object and cannot return null (see answers below!), imho the proper way to accomplish the example:

```
var F = function(i) { if( i > 5 ) throw( 'tooMuch' ); this.i = i; }
try { 
   for( var f = new F(1); true; f = new F(f.i) ) {
      ...
   }
} catch( er ) { null; }
```

this uses `throw/catch` for loop control - has not been my cup of tea, but the new javascript specs on `iterators` uses this same mechanism, so I probably need to be thinking to myself "thow exceptions", not "thow errors".

Comment: what do you mean by guts? Also, it wouldn't make any sense if you could return null when creating an object because you don't see it returning itself anywhere.

Comment: @ilia: guts, ie, attributes - eg, this.jy.  do not understand your second comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ou ***CAN*** return your ***own object*** instead of the object given by `new` -- but remember it has to be an object -- `null` won't do -- although ironically `typeof null` is also `object`

```
function F(x) {
  if (x < 10) return new Number(0);

  this.x = x;
}
```

now you can do your thing...

```
for ( var i = 1, k = new F(i); k; k = new F(++i) ) {
  // dance .~.~.~.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`new F` returns an object.

`null` is a value not an object.

You cannot do this

Comment: that's what I thought, although you are the purveyor of bad news lately ;)

Comment: @cc_young why would you expect `new f` to return `null` ? What's the use case? You can get a factory to return `null` instead. (Like `document.getElementById`)

Comment: actually, from syntax analysis, did not expect `new f()` to return null, but to me seemed counter-intuitive so wanted to cover bases.  using a "factory" or a wrapper function, as per example by @greengit, does the trick, eliminating, as you suspect, the use case, but imho not as elegantly as the ability to return null outright - but that's just my personal opinion etc etc.

Comment: @cc_young the real question is why would `new F` ever return anything that's not an object. Syntax abuse and black magic.

Comment: I think we can disagree on this.  in many languages null takes on many black magic attributes.  indeed, in javascript, null itself is an object.  not fighting, but just to illustrate the different view point, I think an equally valid "real" question is why would `new F` be prevented from returning null? these are language design problems that I both find interesting and respect the decisions made. anyway, to quote, la-tee-dah.

Comment: @cc_young The question is why would it return `null`. It's similar to Say a `clone` keyword. `clone obj` would return a "clone" of `obj`. Why would you want that `clone` to ever be `null` (unless you call `clone null` but that's annoying edge-case we are going to ignore).

Comment: @ccyoung let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1624/discussion-between-raynos-and-cc-young)